# Different ways of looking at finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

$\DeclareMathOperator{\split}{split}$
I am interested in a list consisting of different points of view that one could take to look at finite fields. So far I found five different aspects (see the list below). I would appreciate if this list could be checked for correctness and expanded by other points of view.

Let $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ be a finite field, $\eta \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ a primitive element, $f \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ dividing $x^{p^n}-x$ and $\alpha_i,\dots,\alpha_n$ all the roots of $f$. Denote the splitting field of a polynomial $g$ over some field $\mathbb{F}$ by $\split(g,\mathbb{F})$. Then $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is isomorphic to

- $\split(x^{p^n}-x,\mathbb{F}_p)$
- $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$
- $\mathbb{F}_p(\eta)$
- $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(f)$

Comment: $\mathbb F_p[\alpha_i]$ is all of the field, for any one $\alpha_i,$ whether $\alpha_i$ is primitive or not.

Comment: Everywhere you’ve written $\mathbb F_p(\cdot)$ you could have written $\mathbb F_p[\cdot].$

Comment: More generally, if $d\mid n$ then there is is an irreducible polynomial $f_d\in\mathbb F_{p^d}[x]$ of degree $n/d$ with $$\mathbb F_{p^n}\cong \mathbb F_{p^d}[x]/(f_d).$$

Comment: In fact, every where you’ve used $\mathbb F_p,$ there is an equivalent for $\mathbb F_{p^d}.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ouch, I misread what $\alpha_i$ were. Sorry.